# How can I extract and save image frames from a large number of videos all at once using OpenCV Python?

Tags: python, image, opencv, video, frames

My question is:
Can I extract image frames from a large number of videos all at once using OpenCV Python and save it in a folder in the form of .jpg or .png?

I have written an OpenCV Python code which extracts image frames from 1 video when I provide the video path of that video as the input.
Also I have provided the output path of the image frames extracted to a different directory.
But, my code can take 1 video path at once and extract image frames from that video.

Is there any way, where I can provide a path of the directory having 'n' number of videos and I can extract the image frames from all those n videos at a time in a sequential order and save it in the output path directory?

Below is my Python code using OpenCV module for extracting image frames from a single video.

```
import cv2
import os

video_path = 'C:/Users/user/Videos/abc.mp4' # video name
output_path = 'C:/Users/user/Pictures/image_frames' # location on ur pc

if not os.path.exists(output_path): 
    os.makedirs(output_path)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
index = 0

while cap.isOpened():
    Ret, Mat = cap.read()

    if Ret:
        index += 1
        if index % 29 != 0:
            continue

        cv2.imwrite(output_path + '/' + str(index) + '.png', Mat)

    else:
        break

cap.release()
```

Comment: You'd have an easier and likely faster time using/scripting the command-line ffmpeg tool.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that you code is correct, you can create a function with your code, list files in directory and pass then to your function.

```
import cv2
import os
# your function
def video2frames( video_file, output_path )
    if not os.path.exists(output_path):
        os.makedirs(output_path)
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
    index = 0        
    while cap.isOpened():
        Ret, Mat = cap.read()
        if Ret:
            index += 1
            if index % 29 != 0:
                continue
            cv2.imwrite(output_path + '/' + str(index) + '.png', Mat)
        else:
            break
    cap.release()
    return

def multiple_video2frames( video_path, output_path )
    list_videos = os.listdir(video_path)
    for video in list_videos:
        video_base = os.path.basename(video)
        input_file = video_path + '/' + video
        out_path = output_path + '/' + video_base
        video2frames(input_file, out_path)
    return

# run all
video_path = 'C:/Users/user/Videos/' # all videos
output_path = 'C:/Users/user/Pictures/' # location on ur pc
multiple_video2frames( video_path, output_path )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your code is working perfect !!

Comment: Your welcome. Do not forget to vote and mark as answer.

Comment: I've marked your answer as correct, but I'm not yet able to vote as I don't have required reputations to cast a vote.

Comment: @JoséD.Tascón-Vidarte What I understand `if index % 29 != 0:` used to determine, the video use 30 fps. is that right?

Comment: For some reason the author is dropping that frame. To avoid this you can remove the lines:
> if index % 29 != 0: ;
>   continue;